# ActionScript 3: Arguments in empty constructor in class

Tags: actionscript-3

I have source code of one software, that have maded in ActionScript 3 (there about 3000).
I'm not familiar with AS3. And I have to understand one problem.

I have 2 class.
Frist of them

```
package test.test1.test2
{ 
   public class ClassName extends Object 
   { 
      public function ClassName() 
      { 
         super(); 
      } 
      public static function function1(var1:*) : ClassName 
      { 
         var varX:ClassName = new ClassName(); 
         varX.class_var = var1.subvar;
         return varX; 
      } 
      public var class_var:Number;
   } 
}
```

The second class:

```
package test.test4.test5
{ 
....... 
   import package test.test1.test2.ClassName; 
........ 
      public static function function2(loc_var1:int, loc_var1:int) : Object 
      { 
         var _loc16_:ClassName = null; 
......... 
               _loc16_ = ClassName(_loc15_.xxx); 

.....
```

I don't know exactly the data type of *loc15*.

How is it possible??
As I know function2 is used in the program and it works.

Comment: It will be a lot easier to understand the original code instead of what the decompiler spit out.

Comment: Decompiled code isn't it?

Comment: It was lost. ( I have only decompiler files. The problem is that I can't understand how empty constructor can have arguments. I sure for 100% that there only one class ClassName.